# Default page number on page size change

Tags: algorithm, pagination

I'm trying to set value of a default page number when user will change page size (items per page)

I'm talkin about secenarion where I'm on a page #10 of 100 with 10 rows then I will change to 25 it will update to page #4 and then will change to 50 it will update to page #2.

The other way is when I'm on a page #2 with 100 rows then switch to 50 rows I will end on page #3 , then changing to 25 items per page - page #5 and for 10 - page #11

I thought that

```
defaultPageNo = round(((currentPageNo * prevRowSize) / currentRowSize )) + 1;
```

is going to work but it works only going from 100 items per page down.

Any tips how it should to looks like correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr

```
nextPage = floor(oldPage * oldLimit / nextLimit)
```

or better

```
nextPage = floor(offset / nextLimit)
```

---

A "standard" way of thinking is in terms of `offset`, `limit`

- `offset` is the number of elements you skip (more precisely the index of the element where you are at)
- `limit` is the number of elements you display

In your vocabulary,

- the `pagination` is the `limit`
- `currentPage = floor(offset / limit)`

When you change pagination (aka `limit`) you don't want to change the `offset`, only the page and there is indeed no knowledge (in the division) about whether limit increases or not.

Now since offset is the invariant we sure want to know it.

- If you know it, just use it.

`nextPage = floor(offset / nextLimit)`

- else we may **approximate** it: you see we have lost information when applying floor. I'll assume we want the first element currently displayed to be displayed on the newPage

```
if currentPage == k, then offset == k * limit + r (k,r integers, r < limit)
```

Since we want to display the first one, we will say `offset = k * limit + 0 = currentPage * limit`

Finally

`nextPage = floor(offset / nextLimit) = floor(oldPage * oldLimit / nextLimit)`

e.g

```js
const changePagination = (old, newLimit) => {
  const next = { page: Math.floor(old.page * old.limit / newLimit), limit: newLimit }
  console.log(next, 'next display at offset:', next.page * next.limit)
  return next
}
let old = { page: 238, limit: 1 } // make some coll
old = changePagination(old, 1)
old = changePagination(old, 2)
old = changePagination(old, 4) // notice we show a few "new" elements
old = changePagination(old, 8)
old = changePagination(old, 5)
old = changePagination(old, 11)
console.log('ill stuff')
old = changePagination({ page: 60, limit: 1 }, 21)
old = changePagination(old, 20)
old = changePagination(old, 21)
old = changePagination(old, 20)
old = changePagination(old, 21) // first offset is 0 ?!! while initial is 60
```

- As you see the first element displayed can be potentially lower than the one we want.
- !Then we (wrongly) assume that the **first** element displayed is the one we want to be displayed after the new limit.

So if you have the offset, **keep it** instead of guessing it from old pagination

Comment: I got it to work with "default" page. Big thanks for well documented explanation!